# Understanding decltype(auto) difference in case of template vs auto functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, auto, decltype

I need help understanding why the return type of updateElementUsingTemplate differ from updateElementUsingAuto in the below provided code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;

template<typename Container, typename Index>
decltype(auto) updateElementUsingTemplate(Container&& container, Index index)
{    
    std::cout << "Template Return Type : "<<
    type_id_with_cvr<decltype( container[index] )>().pretty_name() << '\n';
    return container[index];
}

decltype(auto) updateElementUsingAuto(auto&& container, size_t index)
{
    std::cout << "Auto Return Type : "<<
    type_id_with_cvr<decltype( container[index] )>().pretty_name() << '\n';
    return container[index];
}

int main() {
    std::array<int,2> arr= {1,2};
    updateElementUsingTemplate( arr, 1 ) = 12;
    updateElementUsingAuto( arr, 1 );// = 12;
    //Generates compiler error if uncommented: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.
    //Why is type being returned "int" in above statement?
    std::cout << "Auto Returned Type : "<< 
type_id_with_cvr<decltype( updateElementUsingAuto(arr,1) )>().pretty_name() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Template Returned Type : "<<
type_id_with_cvr<decltype( updateElementUsingTemplate(arr,1) )>().pretty_name() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Actual Result:
Template Return Type : int&
Auto Return Type : int&
**Auto Returned Type : int**

Template Returned Type : int&

Expected Result :
Template Return Type : int&
Auto Return Type : int&
**Auto Returned Type : int&**

Template Returned Type : int&

I was expecting updateElementUsingAuto and updateElementUsingTemplate both to return int&, where as actual results returned are int and int& respectively.
Why is there difference in return type of both functions?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Edit 1: As mentioned by @cpplearner, this issue seems to be a gcc bug.
If someone still wants to use the syntax, you can do so by using trailing type syntax :
    decltype(auto) updateElementUsingAuto(auto&& container, size_t index) -> decltype( container[index] ){ ... }

Comment: This seems like a GCC bug. Note that `auto` parameter type is a GCC extension implemented since GCC 4.9, and is not (yet) part of any published ISO C++ standard.

Comment: Probably related to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69448

Comment: @cpplearner I agree with your opinion that it seems to be a gcc bug. If you could answer it i will mark it accepted and close the issue.FYI, I tried to report the same on bugzilla (as i want to be sure that it is rectified) but the new account creation has been blocked and i am unable to do so at the moment. Thanks for your help.